# Angular Component not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am using the `ng2-select` component to extend another component - I called it `my-dropdown-field`. However the `ng2-select` component does not render for some reason. The issue does not seem to be in the ng2 control, but rather in the wrapper control I created. I am however not able to figure out what is causing this. There are no errors thrown either. If I use `ng2-select` on it's own its working fine. I created a reproducible stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-select-angular2

If you run this, you will see there is no ng2-select control being rendered. If you comment out the below section from the app.component.html:

**Doesn't work**

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (submit)="showForm()">
    <my-dropdown-field 
    name="country"
    [items]="items"
    [selectedItem]="active"
    formControlName="country">
    </my-dropdown-field>
  <button (click)="showForm()">Show</button>
</form>
```

and uncomment this from the top:

**Works**

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (submit)="showForm()">
    <ng-select 
    name="country"
    [(ngModel)]="active"
    [(active)]="active"
    [items]="items"
    formControlName="country">
    </ng-select>
  <button (click)="showForm()">Show</button>
</form>
```

Then you will see that it works just fine.

Here is the link to the original ng2-select component:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're overwriting ng2-select's property `items`. 
Originally it's a setter (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/blob/development/src/select/select.ts#L269) so this line `@Input() items: Array<string> = [];` is changing original behavior.

A workaround in this situation is to use different name for this property (`options`, `objects`, etc)
Here's  working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-select-angular2-tof6ko?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes, I see that was the issue. I also had to add the bootstrap.min.css. The stackblitz has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

MyDropdownFieldComponent should implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) 
if you want that it works with ngModel and reactive forms.

[selectedItem] should not be an array or change the name

On AppComponent, create the form in ngOnInit instead of the constructor

Comment: `MyDropdownFieldComponent` extends `SelectComponent` which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Do I still need to manually implement it again? `selectedItem` is actually an array, according to the `ng2-select` documentation.

Comment: I think you don't need to implement the interface again, but you can override the methods of the interface according to your needs.

I am reading: https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/
Try to double check every input and output and avoid double binding.

Whatever is on: country: new FormControl('', []) should initialize the dropdown. If you put: country: new FormControl('Australia', []). Your active should be Australia. Australia should appear on writeValue method if you do a console log there